# Iterating over multiple excel sheets in a an excel files

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have an Excel file that has about 30 tabs in it. These are the column names
`Promotion_Type`, `Product  New Accounts`, `% of Total`, `Total Balances`, `% of Total`,    `Average Balances`, `Weighted Average Rate`, `Margin`. I need to perform two operations. Load the sheets as is but specify the data type for each column and then rename them to `Promo_type`, `prod`, `New_Acct`, `New_Per`, `Total_Bal`, `Per_Bal`, `Avg_Bal`, `Wtd_Rate`, `Marg`.

I'm trying to use the `purrr` library in `tidyverse` package.

I am not sure what is wrong with this code. Your input is highly appreciated.

```
`path <- "data_raw/Products/Product.xlsx"

combined_data <- 
  excel_sheets(path) %>% 
map_df(~{
read_excel(path, sheet = .x, trim_ws = TRUE,
           col_types = c("text", 
                         "text", 
                         "numeric", 
                         "guess", 
                         "numeric", 
                         "guess", 
                         "numeric", 
                         "numeric", 
                         "numeric")) %>%
colnames(combined_data) <- c("Promotion_Type",
                      "Product",
                      "New_Accounts",
                      "New_Acct_Percent",
                      "Total_Balances",
                      "Percent_Balance",
                      "Average_Balances",
                      "Weighted_Average_Rate",
                      "Margin")})
```

`

Comment: Which error do yo get when running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
library(tidyverse)

path <- "data_raw/Products/Product.xlsx"

ctypes <- c("text", "text", "numeric", "guess", "numeric", "guess", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")
cnames <- c("Promotion_Type", "Product", "New_Accounts", "New_Acct_Percent", "Total_Balances",
           "Percent_Balance", "Average_Balances", "Weighted_Average_Rate", "Margin")

combined_data <- path %>%
  excel_sheets() %>%
  map_df(~ read_excel(path, sheet = .x, trim_ws = TRUE, col_types = ctypes))

colnames(combined_data) <- cnames
```